# Can i get complete friend list from facebook graph API 2.2 with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using below code,this code will return only the users who use my app:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'GET',
      '/me/friends'
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

result:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I have also used this:
$taggable = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/taggable_friends' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

but it return only array.

Answer (score 1):

With v2.0, only users who are using the App too show up in the friend list.

See changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

There is also "invitable_friends" and "taggable_friends", the first one is for game invitations only and the second one is for tagging only.